PyQt - Hidden widget leaves space in Window
I have the following code that produces a window with a QTableView visible. I add a QTextEdit to the right but hide it.
When I run the code it looks as though space has been reserved on the right for the TextEdit even though the TableView has a setSizePolicy of Expanding.
What do I need to set so that the TableView initially takes up all the space in the window, then shrinks to accommodate the TextEdit and then expands fully when the TextEdit is hidden?
Thank you in advance.
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QGridLayout, QMainWindow, QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import  QSizePolicy, QTableView, QTextEdit, QWidget

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
# https://www.pythonguis.com/faq/file-image-browser-app-with-thumbnails/
    def runBtn(self):
#https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LCJEyuCZlAY
        if self.hdn == True:
            self.text.show()
            self.hdn = False
        else:
            self.text.hide()
            self.hdn=True

    def __init__(self):            
        super().__init__()
        widget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)
        self.layout = QGridLayout(widget)
        self.hdn = True

        self.Btn = QPushButton('Hide/Show',self)
        self.Btn.clicked.connect(self.runBtn)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.Btn, 0, 0, 1, 1)

        self.view = QTableView()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.view, 1, 0, 48, 50)
        self.view.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding) # /73522221/

        self.text = QTextEdit()
        self.text.hide()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.text, 1, 50, 48, 2)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
window.show()
app.exec_()


Why are you using those values for the grid column and the spans? They make very little point, if you want a widget that is initially larger, you should subclass it and override its sizeHint(). Using large values for columns and rows (and spans) to make widgets bigger is inappropriate, as that's not the purpose of column/row indexes. Also, QTableView already has an expanding size policy by default, like all widgets that inherit from QAbstractScrollArea.

After spending sometime looking for a solution, I came across a hint at Is there any way to remove a QWidget in a QGridLayout? indicating that I would have to remove the widget. So change runBtn to:
    def runBtn(self):
#https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LCJEyuCZlAY
        if self.hdn == True:
            self.text.show()
            self.hdn = False
            self.layout.addWidget(self.text, 1, 50, 48, 2)
        else:
            self.text.hide()
            self.hdn=True
            self.layout.removeWidget(self.text) # /13184250/

and change the start of init to:
    def __init__(self):            
        super().__init__()
# need to set window size, otherwise the window
#   expands when self.text is added/removed initially
        self.setGeometry(1, 700,500,700)

and remove:
self.layout.addWidget(self.text, 1, 50, 48, 2)
This works, but a far better solution using QBoxLayouts at:
Adjust widths of QHBoxLayout
is a far better solution.
PS Thanks, musicamante
